# Calculation in angular observable subscription delivers wrong data

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, rxjs-observables

I have a observable which delivers data in the following structure:

```
export interface expResults {
  user: User;
  results: {
    experiment: Experiment
    attempts: number
    passed: boolean
  }[];
}
```

What I want to do now is to calculate the rate of experiments performed at least once. For example:

```
  Donald;
  results: {
    experiment: Experiment1
    attempts: 3
    passed: true
  }[];

  Micky;
  results: {
    experiment: Experiment1
    attempts: 0
    passed: false
  }[];

  Frank;
  results: {
    experiment: Experiment1
    attempts: 3
    passed: false
  }[];

  Lisa;
  results: {
    experiment: Experiment1
    attempts: 0
    passed: false
  }[];
```

In this case I expect the output "0,5" because 50% of the users tried the experiment at least once.

I use the following code but it returns no data. Can someone see my mistake?

```
expResults: Observable<expResults[]> = of();
ngOnInit(): void {
this.expResults = this.dataService.getData(topic);
this.expResults.pipe(map((resultSet2) => {
            return resultSet2.reduce((acc, resultSet) => {
              resultSet.results.forEach((t) => {
                if (acc[t.attempts] == null) acc[t.attempts] = [];
                else {
                  if (t.attempts == 0) {
                    acc[t.attempts].push(0);
                  } else {
                    acc[t.attempts].push(1);
                  }
                }});
              return acc;
            }, {});
          }),
          map((resultsObj) => {
            return Object.keys(resultsObj).map((key) => {
              const count = resultsObj[key].length;
              const sum = resultsObj[key].reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
              const rate = sum / count;
              this.ChartData[0].data.push(Number(rate));
            });
          })
        )
          .subscribe();
}
```

Comment: Its not clear what you are trying to do. Is this.expResults a stream of a single item or an array.? If its a single value, what are you expecting to do? While values are coming through the stream to calculate a rate at the moment (based on all previous values that came in the past) or what?

Comment: Sorry if i missed something. Its a stream of data from the backend. Its defined like: expResult: Observable<expResult[]> = of();. In ngOnInit it gets filled with the data using a service. The service is okay because i use the data for other calculation so im sure the problem is somewhere in the upper code. I hope i could specify the problem.

Comment: question unclear - please update (not in the comments). FYI for observable streams sticking a `tap(data=>console.log(data))` e.g. `.pipe(map(...), tap(...), map(...))` inside the pipe is common debugging technique.

Comment: Sorry I was sure it contains all important information. I edited the question and hope, its clear.

Comment: Do you fetch data only once on ngOnInit, or dataService can fetch it multiple times so you can have a stream of values on this.expResults?

Comment: I do it only once in the beginning of ngOnInit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.expResults.pipe(map((result: expResults[]) => {

  // Calculate number of experiments performed at least once
  const numberOfPerformed = result.reduce((acc, item) => {
    // If attempts > 0 then add 1 to the sum
    acc += (item.results.attempts ? 1 : 0);
    return acc;
  }, 0)

  // Calculate rate
  return numberOfPerformed / result.length;

})).subscribe((rate) => {
  // rate
})
```